# Qt - Saving a custom QGraphicsScene with custom QGraphicsItems

Tags: qt, file-io, save, qgraphicsscene

I created a public QGraphicsItem `Node` class which has getter/setter methods for a bunch of properties relevant to my application. The application is a diagram editor in which the users design models. This `Node` class is used to populate an also public QGraphicsScene `Diagram` class.

I'm now trying to implement a load/save mechanism in the app that enables users to save and reuse the models - editing them as they were when they saved. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to attack this problem.

I already know I have to get the relevant properties for the QGraphicsItem objects and save those to file, and then on load, reconstruct the scene using the data I saved. My question is: when I use the `QGraphicsScene::items()` function, it returns a `QList<QGraphicsItem *>`. What can I do to have it return a `QList<Node *>`?

If I get a list of all the nodes I appended to the scene, I know what to do next.

I began to realise that I will probably have to reimplement the `items()` function in my `Diagram` class, but I was hoping I could get away with it more easily. In this case, can someone please explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to implement the `QGraphicsItem::type()` method and using `qgraphicsitem_cast` to cast into the desired class. In your case, you could subclass all your custom GraphicsItems from a common base class.

Your base class would look like this:

```
class MyGraphicsItem: public QGraphicsItem
{
    enum { Type = UserType + 1 };

    int type() const { return Type; }
};
```

Your Node and your Link class would inherit this base:

```
class Node : public MyGraphicsItem
{
    // ... 
};

class Link : public MyGraphicsItem
{
    // ... 
};
```

Somewhere else you could cast a QGraphicsItem into your base class `MyGraphicsItem` like this for example:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> allItems = graphicsScene->items();
foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, allItems) {
    // Using qgraphicsitem_cast 
    MyGraphicsItem* graphicsItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<MyGraphicsItem*>(item);
    if (graphicsItem) {
        // Do something with MyGraphicsItem
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I also have a public QGraphicsItem `Link` class. The `items()` method will also return these instances. How would you adapt your code to _test_ if the item is of class `Node`? I don't want/need to handle the `Link` objects...

Comment: You could solve this by using a common base class for all your items and inherit your `Node` and your `Link` class from it. Later on, you could use `qgraphicsitem_cast` to cast into that base class. I've updated the code to show that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, from what I found online, the _test_ part of my question is simply to test `if(graphicsItem!=0)`. This is only true if after the cast, `graphicsItem` isn't of type `MyGraphicsItem`, right?

Comment: You're right. It is essential after the `qgraphicsitem_cast` to check if the pointer is not 0. I've updated the code.

Comment: Just another question: is there any specific reason why I can't/shouldn't simply define the `type()` method in the `Node` class directly?

Comment: You should redefine the type() method in the class into which you will cast the QGraphicsItem to. So you could redefine the `type()` method in your `Node` class, if you wish to do a `qgraphicsitem_cast` to a `Node` class like this: `Node *specificNode = qgraphicsitem_cast<Node*>(aGraphicsItem);`

Comment: Got it. I ended up defining the method in the `Node` class and used what you posted now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

While the items function returns a list of QGraphicsItem pointers, you could try either dynamic_casting to check if it's a Node pointer or use the Qt metadata and the type() function.

However, the method I often use, which can help you in other ways too, is to maintain a unique id for every type of object and a static lists of item Ids. For example: -

```
class BaseItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    public:
        BaseItem(QGraphicsItem* parent)
          : QGraphicsItem(parent), m_Id(m_NextId++) // initialising the object's unique Id
        {
        }

        unsigned int ID() const
        {
            return m_Id;
        }

    private:
        static unsigned int m_NextId; // the next Object Id, initialised to 0 in implementation
        unsigned int m_Id; // the object's unique Id

}

class Node : public BaseItem
{
    public:
        Node(QGrahicsItem* parent)
          : BaseItem(parent)
        {
            m_NodesList.push_back(m_Id);
        }

    private:
        static QList<unsigned int> m_sNodesList; // all Node ids in the scene

        QList<unsigned int> m_linkedNodeList; // linked nodes
}
```

All items added to the GraphicsScene are inherited from the BaseItem

You also have a static list of Node Ids, so you can iterate through all of them for loading / saving and you can add a static helper function in the base class to return a list of Nodes, by searching through the List of Node Ids and matching them to their node pointers in the scene.

This architecture also allows you to include a list of linked node ids in each Node object, rather than using the parent / child system of Qt, which in the case of a node diagram, isn't always what is needed.

Overall, I've used this architecture for many QGraphicsScene applications and it has really made development very easy for items that have complex links to other items.

Comment: Thank you, this seems very interesting! Although I think that the approach by @thomas_b seems simpler. I realise the benefits of indexing the object types, but it might be too much for what I need. +1 though :)

Comment: No problem, I just thought I'd put it out there for reference and maybe others will benefit from it in the future.